# Android Linear Layout clipping with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I have a requirement to build a custom view as

[image]

[image]

I implemented this as a custom view which extends a LinearLayout, the LinearLayout contains two more LinearLayouts (for each row), and each element is another custom view which extends a RelativeLayout and contains the functionality for animation/state changes.

The problem I am having is .. because the animation to grow the circle with the arrow scales the imageview, the imageview is clipped by its parent container since the size is set once drawn. I can call setScaleX/Y on the parent itself before scaling the imageview.. but then I get some weird behaviour ... there must be a simpler solution !

Class for layout file

```
public class CameraCalibrationIndicatorCircles extends LinearLayout {

ArrayList<CalibrationIndicatorCircle> circles;
int currentCircleIndex = 0;

public CameraCalibrationIndicatorCircles(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize(context);
}

public CameraCalibrationIndicatorCircles(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize(context);
}

public CameraCalibrationIndicatorCircles(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialize(context);
}

public void initialize(Context context){
    inflate(context, R.layout.camera_calibration_indication_circles_view, this);

    circles = new ArrayList<>();

    CalibrationIndicatorCircle
            c0,     c1,    c2,     c3,     c4,
            c5,     c6,    c7,     c8,     c9;

    c0 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c0);
    c1 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c1);
    c2 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c2);
    c3 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c3);
    c4 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c4);
    c5 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c5);
    c6 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c6);
    c7 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c7);
    c8 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c8);
    c9 = (CalibrationIndicatorCircle)findViewById(R.id.c9);

    circles.add(c0);
    circles.add(c1);
    circles.add(c2);
    circles.add(c3);
    circles.add(c4);
    circles.add(c5);
    circles.add(c6);
    circles.add(c7);
    circles.add(c8);
    circles.add(c9);

    currentCircleIndex = 0;
    circles.get(currentCircleIndex).indicateCurrent();

}

public void successfulEvent(){
    if(currentCircleIndex < CalibrationBox.MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_CAMERA_IMAGES_FOR_CALIB) {
        circles.get(currentCircleIndex).indicateSucess(1,1, true);
        currentCircleIndex++;
        if (currentCircleIndex < CalibrationBox.MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_CAMERA_IMAGES_FOR_CALIB)
            circles.get(currentCircleIndex).indicateCurrent();
    }
}

}
```

Layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="4"
android:clipChildren="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CalibrationIndicatorCircle
        android:id="@+id/c9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Single circle view class

```
public class CalibrationIndicatorCircle extends RelativeLayout {

ImageView mWaiting, mCurrent, mSuccess, mCompleted;
boolean mIsCurrent = false;
Context mContext;

public CalibrationIndicatorCircle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize(context);
}

public CalibrationIndicatorCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize(context);
}

public CalibrationIndicatorCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialize(context);
}

public void initialize(Context context){
    inflate(context, R.layout.calibration_indicator_circle_view, this);
    mWaiting = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.waiting);
    mCurrent = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.current);
    mSuccess = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.success);
    mCompleted = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.completed);
    mCurrent.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    mSuccess.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    mCompleted.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
}

public void indicateCurrent(){
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mWaiting.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mCurrent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mIsCurrent = true;
        }
    });
}

public void indicateSucess(final float scaleX, final float scaleY, final boolean hideCheckMark){

    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Animate
            mSuccess.setScaleX(0);
            mSuccess.setScaleY(0);
            mSuccess.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mCurrent.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mWaiting.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mSuccess
                    .animate()
                    .scaleX(scaleX)
                    .scaleY(scaleY)
                    .setDuration(500)
                    .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                            if(hideCheckMark) {

                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                mSuccess.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                                                mCompleted.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        }, 300);
                                    }
                                }).start();

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    })
                    .start();
        }
    });

}

public void hideUntilReady() {
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mWaiting.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mCurrent.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mSuccess.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mCompleted.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Single circle layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:clipChildren="false">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_success_icon"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/success"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_current_icon"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/current"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_waiting_icon"
    android:id="@+id/waiting"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_taken_icon"
    android:id="@+id/completed"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setClipChildren(false)` in  `ViewGroup` for `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` in which `ImageView` is contained in.

Comment: Tried this in like every layer of the layout up the heirarchy .. is has to do with the view size being set once drawn regardless of the animation

Comment: I have been using this from long time and it's working great. We could then only be able to dig further if you post the code with xml.